# Simple marker rendering

Tags: javascript, ajax, leaflet

I am trying to render in a leaflet map that should render a single marker. I am building the JavaScript as follows.

1. build the map
2. an even listener for when the user opens the page where the map is rendered.

I query as follows:

```
@company = Company.friendly.find_by(
                        slug: [ params[:id],
                        params[:company_id] ])
respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json:
        {
          type: "Feature",
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [@company.longitude, @company.latitude] # this part is tricky
          },
          properties: {
            "title": @company.name,
            "address": @company.street_address,
          }
        }
      }
    end
```

I console log the steps and everything seems to "work". The data is loaded and `data.responseJSON` renders as follows:

```
geometry: {…}
​​coordinates: Array [ 1.5918642, 43.7189496 ]​​
type: "Point"
<prototype>: Object { … }
properties: Object { title: "Acme SaS", address: "xxx", "marker-color": "#FFFFFF", … }
type: "Feature"
```

However, the map does not ​render as wanted. Only a grey box shows up. If I provide with a lat, Lon array, the map renders a map.

```
function buildCompanyMap() {

  document.getElementById('company_map').innerHTML = "<div id='map' style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'></div>";

  console.log("script #1: %o", document.getElementById('company_map'));
  console.log("script #2: %o", document.getElementById('map'));

  var data = $.ajax({
      url: "#companies/company.json",
      dataType: "json",
      success: console.log("company data successfully loaded."),
      error: function(xhr) {
          alert(xhr.statusText)
      }
  });

  console.log("script #3: %o", $);

  console.log("script #4: %o", data);

  $.when(data).done(function() {
    var map = new L.Map('map', {
        dragging: false,
        tap: false,
        scrollWheelZoom: false
      });

    var osmUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        osmAttribution = 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors,' +
                        ' <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>',
        osmLayer = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {maxZoom: 18, attribution: osmAttribution});

    map.addLayer(osmLayer);

    console.log("script #5: %o", data.responseJSON);

    var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
        radius: 8,
        fillColor: "#ff7800",
        color: "#000",
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0.8
    };

    L.geoJSON(data.responseJSON, {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
        }
    }).addTo(map);

  });
};

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  if (document.getElementById('company_map') == null) {
    //console.log('true')
  }
  else {
    buildCompanyMap();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A correction. I have removed the use of jQuery in the correction. The main issue was that you don't set anywhere a map center and a zoom. I've changed the behaviour by zooming the map to GeoJSON extent (e.g `map.fitBounds(jsonLayer.getBounds());`)

You could also made the change by setting a map center and a zoom like described in [this link to official doc](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-example).

```js
function buildCompanyMap() {

  document.getElementById('company_map').innerHTML = "<div id='map' style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'></div>";

  console.log("script #1: %o", document.getElementById('company_map'));
  console.log("script #2: %o", document.getElementById('map'));

  var map = new L.Map('map', {
      dragging: false,
      tap: false,
      scrollWheelZoom: false
    });

  var osmUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      osmAttribution = 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors,' +
                      ' <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>',
      osmLayer = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {maxZoom: 18, attribution: osmAttribution});

  map.addLayer(osmLayer);

  console.log("script #5: %o", data.responseJSON);

  var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
      radius: 8,
      fillColor: "#ff7800",
      color: "#000",
      weight: 1,
      opacity: 1,
      fillOpacity: 0.8
  };

  fetch('#companies/company.json', {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then (json => {
      var jsonLayer = L.geoJSON(json, {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
        }
      })
      jsonLayer.addTo(map);
      map.fitBounds(jsonLayer.getBounds());
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log('Error on fetch operation: ' + error.message);
    });

};

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  if (document.getElementById('company_map') == null) {
    //console.log('true')
  }
  else {
    buildCompanyMap();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I might have an issue with my formatting on the son response as I get: "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Comment: Copy the content of your returned GeoJSON to https://geojsonlint.com. It validates you are using GeoJSON

Comment: well, it's valid geojson

When I modify the map var and add a set view on dummy data, the map will render o the coordinates.

  var map = new L.Map('map', {
      dragging: false,
      tap: false,
      scrollWheelZoom: false
    }).setView([39.045753, -76.641273], 9);

Comment: Yes but without the GeoJSON. It's the issue here. Made some changes in the fetch (adding headers to explicitly ask for JSON output and catch statement to help debug error)

Comment: You got it solved.  Thanks a bunch. So the solution was to be be explicit by adding headers.